# Perl mail message error handling

Tags: perl, email

I'm trying to quickly process inbound messages through a postfix mail server. I need a way to log and classify bounced mails. I want to determine the error code from the message to tell if it was a mailbox full or host unknown. Is there a perl module that can parse the message and give me the error code?

Comment: Please update this post if you find something more useful; the rest of us are also interested in what you find!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`Mail::DeliveryStatus::BounceParser`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mail-DeliveryStatus-BounceParser/)

I haven't used it so can't vouch for it and there may [other modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=mail+bounce&mode=module) on [`CPAN`](http://search.cpan.org/) which fit the bill.

However anything from [Ricardo Signes](http://search.cpan.org/%7Erjbs/) especially when [e-mail](http://emailproject.perl.org/) related often hits the spot.

/I3az/

PS.  This was something that I was going to look up soon for $work.  So good to get the early leg up!